# Docker bind mount volume cannot be chown

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I bound volume for app in container to read db, while it was user home folder, it was ok.
But when i use */media/s1...*, which is hdd of server, i got permission denied.
Inside of container my target folder has nobody:nogroup owners.
Also trying to create user, change owners in entrypoint.sh, chown failed with target folder, but parents changing ok.

Reproduction of my problem (Commented - trying by adding user.):

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
 
#USER root
#RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gosu
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#USER_ID=${LOCAL_UID:-9001}
#GROUP_ID=${LOCAL_GID:-9001}

#echo "Starting with UID: $USER_ID, GID: $GROUP_ID"
#useradd -u $USER_ID -o -m user
#groupmod -g $GROUP_ID user
#export HOME=/home/user
#chown -R ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} /root; echo $?

#exec /usr/sbin/gosu ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} "$@"

exec "$@"
```

Building and running

```
docker build -t busy11 .
 docker run -it --rm --name user-test -v $DATA_PATH:$DATA_CPATH -e LOCAL_UID=$LOCAL_UID -e LOCAL_GID=$LOCAL_GID -e DATA_PATH=$DATA_PATH -e DATA_CPATH=$DATA_CPATH busy11
```

DATA_PATH - local path DATA_CPATH - container path and LOCAL_UID, LOCAL_GID, local - ids,
as recommended in https://techflare.blog/permission-problems-in-bind-mount-in-docker-volume/

Comment: It's common to use an option like `docker run -u $(id -u):$(id -g)` to specify the numeric host user and group IDs to help resolve this sort of issue; you do not need to create the user inside the container nor pass the IDs as environment variables.  Does this help the setup at all?

Comment: My setup not work, we changed directory in server to my user and group ownership to test, this temporary solution not good as there are other users of group to read write to it.
I'll try your proposal, thank you

Comment: Group can be done by something like $(getent group group_name | ...),  as it not the same with the name of user, it has other users, or hardcoded